# How can i make sure that my container runs a .bat file before that actual .jar file

Tags: spring, docker, shell

So i have created a java spring application which i want to containerize. The problem is that for the application to work a .bat file needs to be run first. The .bat file starts a simulation of a beer brewing machine and the application itself needs to connect to the simulation.

Im quite new to all this and it is really strange to work with. But this is the dockerfile i have created.

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
#Set working directory of container
WORKDIR /app
#Copies everything into /app directory
COPY . /app/

#Changes directory to Simulation folder
WORKDIR /app/Simulation
#Converts the .bat file to a Linux compatible executeable and run it
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "modifyStart.sh"]
CMD ./modifyStart.sh

#Changes directory back to /app
WORKDIR /app

#Define Jar file and copy to container
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app/app.jar"]
```

The modifyStart.sh is a script that is supposed to modify the .bat file so it can be run by a linux environment. it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

sed -i 's/START \(.*\)/\1 \&/g' /app/Simulation/start.bat
sed -i 's/%~dp0/./g' /app/Simulation/start.bat
sed -i '1i #!/bin/sh' /app/Simulation/start.bat

sh /app/Simulation/start.bat
```

I can create an image of the dockerfile but when i try to spin up the container it gives errors indicating that no connection to the simulation has been made

Comment: A Docker container normally only runs one process.  Can you split up the simulator and the application into two separate containers?

Comment: ("Only runs one process" here means that the only container command is the [last] `ENTRYPOINT`, being passed the [last] `CMD` as arguments.  You can't use multiple of these directives to try to specify multiple commands to run.)

Comment: I have had the thought of running 2 different containers. But i have been put off by the idea because i am not sure how i would go about "connecting" them

Comment: The most common tool for running multiple containers together is Docker Compose, which already does most of the required networking setup; see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.